# Notification Listener Service for System app without user intervention

Tags: android, notifications

I have a system app. In this app I want to capture Notifications, so I'm using NotificationListenerService. But for this service to start we need to do startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS")) and this will get us to the notification access permissions where the user has to check the app and give permission. As my app is a system app is it possible to give permission by default without having the user check the box. I have already tried uses-permission but that is not working. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a long time you've asked for some help but anyway as I was in your situation earlier and found an answer, I'll share it here.

If you want to bypass the Notification access setting for your app, you need to register the NotificationListenerService with the hidden method **registerAsSystemService** of the class. As it is hidden, you have to call it by **reflection** on the NotificationListenerService class (see [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-java-for-android-development-reflection-basics--mobile-3203) for more basic info about reflection)

So, what you should do is:

- Create a subclass that extends NotificationListenerService

We call it NotificationService. Override needed methods (OnNotificationPosted / Removed) and provide an empty constructor
 - Instanciate wherever you want (in a background service or in your start activity)

```
NotificationService ns = new NotificationService();
```

- Create a class which will perform reflection on NotificationListenerService to "reach" the registerAsSystemService method

We call it NotificationProxy. Create a public static method in it as follow:

```
public static void registerAsSystemService(NotificationService ns, Context ctx) {
    String className = "android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService";
    try {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class NotificationListenerService = Class.forName(className);

        //Parameters Types
        //you define the types of params you will pass to the method
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class[] paramTypes= new Class[3];
        paramTypes[0]= Context.class;
        paramTypes[1]= ComponentName.class;
        paramTypes[2] = int.class;

        Method register = NotificationListenerService.getMethod("registerAsSystemService", paramTypes);

        //Parameters of the registerAsSystemService method (see official doc for more info)
        Object[] params= new Object[3];
        params[0]= ctx;
        params[1]= new ComponentName(ctx.getPackageName(), ctx.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        params[2]= -1; // All user of the device, -2 if only current user
        // finally, invoke the function on our instance
        register.invoke(ns, params);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Class not found", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No such method", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "InvocationTarget", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Illegal access", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

- Call the method

From where you have defined your NotificationService instance, call:

```
NotificationProxy.registerAsSystemService(ns, this.getApplicationContext());
```

Hope this will help!

PS : you should not set your service in you manifest as you would do for a simple implementation of the notification service.

PS2: of course, this will only work for system app :)